# Differenza tra dispiace e spiace

Tags: difference, meaning

La mia madrelingua è l'inglese. Mentre imparavo italiano a scuola, avevo sempre sentito "mi dispiace." Un giorno ho visto in un dizionario che "spiace" significa lo stesso che "dispiace." A me "mi spiace" suona più bello, ma è usato in pratica? Ha un altro significato? Qual è più comune?

Comment: A very interesting opinion is expressed by Connie Eyeland in [forum.wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=348016): "mi dispiace" is often more sincere while "mi spiace" is more formal, detached, it does not really imply concern. My opinion is that this also depends on the pronunciation: "mi spiace" with a long "a" sounds sincere; with a short "a" sounds empty.

Answer (score 11):

Io userei "mi spiace" solo in un contesto formale ("mi spiace, ma non è possibile cambiare modalità di pagamento dopo aver chiuso la transazione") mentre "mi dispiace" può essere usato in ogni contesto. Però ho appena consultato il De Mauro e non dà nessuna differenza pratica negli usi.

Answer (score 6):

Cito testualmente dalla [Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/dispiace)

> In italiano non son poche le parole, specie verbi, in cui i prefissi *s-* e *dis-* si fanno concorrenza negli stessi valori, sia in quello negativo, prevalente: *sviare* e *disviare*, *staccare* e *distaccare* (che nascono da attaccare), *stendere* e *distendere*, *smettere* e *dismettere* (con senso un po' diverso), *smembrare* e *dismembrare*, *sdegnare* e *disdegnare*, ecc.; sia in quello intensivo, come in *scacciare* e *discacciare*. *In genere la forma con **dis-** è più letteraria e rara* (sgombrare/disgombrare, scoprire/discoprire), e la si trova in scrittori ad alto tasso di espressività come Dante o Montale. **Ma spiacere e dispiacere hanno avuto una storia parallela e pienamente intercambiabile è il loro uso, almeno nei modi finiti del verbo.** In quelli infiniti (rispondo così ad altra domanda) non coincidono precisamente e spiacente vale dispiaciuto, perché il participio passato dell'uno e quello presente dell'altro sono poco usati (non si dice quasi mai “sono spiaciuto” né “sono dispiacente”, ma “sono spiacente” o “sono dispiaciuto”).

Answer (score 3):

in un contesto più "amichevole" è utilizzato "mi spiace", nel caso più "formale" dispiace.

Ma non c'è alcuna differenza fra i due, quindi se ti piace il verbo spiacere puoi usarlo senza problemi.

Comment: «in un contesto più "amichevole" è utilizzato "mi spiace", nel caso più "formale" dispiace.» Fonte?

Comment: La mia impressione è che *spiacere* sia più formale di *dispiacere*.

Comment: "mi dispiace" io lo suo quando sono sinceramente dispiaciuta per qualcosa, mentre al "mi spiace" lo utilizzo per situazione meno gravi.

Comment: Concordo con i commenti di DaG e egreg, perdonate la riflessione più o meno consistente ma credo che utilizzando la parola più lunga in questo caso si trasmetta maggiormente, implicitamente, un'empatia ed uno sforzo maggiore compiuto nel formulare la frase, un'empatia che si ha verso una persona alla quale si tiene di più di una persona con la quale si intrattengono solo rapporti formali.